# ImageResizer Watermark not appearing

Tags: imageresizer

I have an Azure Function which is attempting to add a watermark to an existing image using ImageResizer version 3.4.3.  The Function executes without error, but a watermark is not applied.  Here is the code, following along from [here](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v3/plugins/watermark):

```
private static void ApplyWatermark(Stream inputStream, string blobName)
{
    var imageConfiguration = Config.Current;
    var plugin = imageConfiguration.Plugins.Get<WatermarkPlugin>();
    if (plugin == null)
    {
        plugin = new WatermarkPlugin();
        plugin.Install(imageConfiguration);
    }
    plugin = imageConfiguration.Plugins.Get<WatermarkPlugin>();
    var imageLayer = new ImageLayer(imageConfiguration)
    {
        Path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(_configuration.Get<string>("BadgeUrl")),
        Align = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    };
    plugin.NamedWatermarks["badge"] = new Layer[]
    {
        imageLayer
    };
    inputStream.Position = 0;
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    imageConfiguration.CurrentImageBuilder.Build(inputStream, outputStream,
        new ResizeSettings("watermark=badge"));
    outputStream.Position = 0;
    _blobStorageRepository.AddorUpdateAsync(_configuration.BlobStorageContainer,
        blobName, outputStream).Wait();
}
```

Any ideas as to why the watermark is not applied?

Comment: Have you tried 4.0? There may have been a related bugfix.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can give ImageLayers physical paths; they would need to be virtual (remove MapPath call).

Comment: @NathanaelJones, using a virtual path fixed the issue.  One other question - any idea why the image size would shrink from 3.8MB to 1.5MB?

Comment: Did the output dimensions change?

Comment: @NathanaelJones, The dimensions did not change.

Comment: I'd need to see both images. Perhaps the watermark reduced the amount of data to compress? They were both jpegs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watermark plugin requires virtual paths like '~/azure/blobimage.jpg'. It doesn't accept physical paths that could be outside of the application root or mounted folders.